# What's the best way to place the text nearby the logo in this case?

Tags: html, css

I want to place the text nearby the logo but **justify-content: center;** is making it more difficult, how can I move the text closer to the logo without having to use **position: left/right** ?

Using **css-position** will affect the responsiveness in the future ?

```css
body {

    background: #19111d;
}

header {

    background: #8761b3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

img {

    width: 100px;
}

p {

    font-size: 30px;
}

nav ul {
    
    display: flex;
}

nav li {

    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img alt="logo" src="logo.png">
            <p>Random Text</p>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Home</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use position over here. I think I'd only try to use padding or margin. 
Did you try wrapping your img and text into separate container for more control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove the `justify-content` and add a `margin-left: auto` to the `nav` instead (to make it right aligned). That should make the text right next to the logo.

If you need to add some space between the logo and the text, just add a `margin-right` to the logo and add the space you need.

```css
body {

    background: #19111d;
}

header {
    background: #8761b3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* Removed justify-content */
}

img {
    width: 100px;
    /* add margin-right to set distance between logo and text */
}

p {

    font-size: 30px;
}

/* Adding this will make the navigation right aligned */
nav {
    margin-left: auto;
}

nav ul {
    
    display: flex;
}

nav li {

    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img alt="logo" src="logo.png">
            <p>Random Text</p>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Home</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header-left {
   display:flex;
   align-items: center;
};

img {
  width: 100px;
}

body {
   background: #19111d;
}

header {
   background: #8761b3;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul {
   display: flex;
}

nav li {
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
 <header>
     <div class="header-left">
        <img alt="logo" src="logo.png">
        <p>Random Text</p>
     </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Home</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```